# Any suggestion as to how group the data in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have the date as shown below;
`P.No   First Name  Last Name   Desc    Sdate   Activity    C Date
2   Barack  hotel   Lung    7/6/2015    cre 6/30/2015
2   Barack  hotel   Lung    7/6/2015    com 6/30/2015
2   Barack  hotel   Lung    7/6/2015    com 6/30/2015
2   Barack  hotel   Lung    7/6/2015    cre 6/30/2015
5   Patrick dirt    Brain   7/27/2015   cre 7/21/2015
5   Patrick dirt    Brain   7/27/2015   com 7/21/2015
5   Patrick dirt    Brain   7/27/2015   com 7/21/2015
5   Patrick dirt    Brain   7/27/2015   cre 7/21/2015
6   Ann Hathway Lung    6/27/2016   cre 6/27/2015
6   Ann Hathway Lung    6/27/2016   cre 6/27/2015
6   Ann Hathway Lung    6/27/2016   can 6/29/2015
10  Travis  Good    Eye 8/27/2018   cre 6/29/2015
10  Travis  Good    Eye 8/27/2018   cre 6/29/2015
10  Travis  Good    Eye 8/27/2018   cre 7/1/2015
10  Travis  Good    Eye 8/27/2018   cre 6/29/2015`

I want to group them and it should display like the one below;

`P.No    First Name  Last Name   Desc    Sdate   Activity    C Date
2   Barack  hotel   Lung    7/6/2015    cre 6/30/2015
5   Patrick dirt    Brain   7/27/2015   cre 7/21/2015
6   Ann Hathway Lung    6/27/2016   cre 6/27/2015
10  Travis  Good    Eye 8/27/2018   cre 6/29/2015`

Appreciate any help on this,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Is it coming from the dataset in reporting service? or is it coming from the query?

If it is coming from the dataset, in the tablix of the report, you can add a row group by p.no, and then add a filter on the group, expression looks like Fields!Activity.value = "cre". Then hide the detail rows.

If it is coming from query, below query should work:

```
select distinct P.[No],   [First Name],  [Last Name],  [Desc],    [Sdate],   [Activity],    [C Date] from p where [Activity] = 'cre'
```

Comment: Its coming from the dataset. I am able to get the Fields!Activity.value = "cre". Can we add multiple values here, like "cre", can, cre, com...... Also I want to add more filter conditions, like "If Sdate < Cdate and Activity =  cre and Cancelled = 0"............etc...                                          I have Multiple conditions, that should satisfy and then show the data for each patient in a series.                                                                                                         Appreciate your help/suggestions on this...

Comment: Answer to your question definitely is yes. In the group filter/visibility tab, you can use "OR" in your expression like IIF(fields!Activity.value = "cre" OR fields!Activity.value = "can" OR ...). However, applying complex filter/visibility conditions will consume resource at report rendering stage. Additionally, the dataset is obtainer before rendering, so if the dataset if too large, your report could become very slow. I suggest you can modify your query or add parameters into your report to optimize the result.